# jQuery dialog dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-dialog

I am looking for a way to make jQuery UI Dialog height dynamically change according to the contents.

Here is my code:

```js
$( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).html( "<iframe src='index.php?act=showProduct&amp;id="+productID+"' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>" );

$( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).dialog(
{
    width: 810,
    height: 590,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui)
    {
    }
});
```

Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Change the height to `"auto"`. See http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-height for more info.

Comment: its written that "auto" is the default value. even thought, if i delete height:.... absolotely, its still isnt working

Answer (score 1):

since the example you are giving is coming from a relative path. You should be able to get the iframe's document's .height()

however you would need to do some CSS trickery to first render the iframe and get its inbrowser document height, then apply that value to your container and then surface the container once the new height is set.

something like ...

taken from here:

```
var doc=document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument;

// Earlier versions of IE or IE8+ where !DOCTYPE is not specified
var doc=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;
```

then you would

```
var iframeDocHeight = $(doc).height(); // assuming it is displayed
$( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).css("height", iframeDocHeight);
```

This of course relies on the basis that you have derived a way (given the rest of your page framework) to allow the iframe to render without immediately displaying it.

I would suggest a combination of `position:absolute` and `visibility:hidden` and then some js wizardry to accomplish this. without a complete rendered html doc, it wouldn't really be useful to suggest an absolute path to this beyond what I have already posted.

Essentially encapsulate the iframe in an element with `overflow:hidden;display:block;height0px;` , but let the iframe render fully (it will be hidden) then examine it and take measurements as necessary

Good luck!

Comment: hey: firstly thank your! secondly: its kinda difficult to do what you've said. perhaps you can help me please to find another way to get into $( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).html the contents of the iframe?

Comment: I'm not really sure of what you are asking - do you want the height or the contents of the iframe? If the prior, my original answer is the approach you should take. If the later, then what is preventing you from using `var iframeHTML = $("yourIFrameObj").html()`  ?